# Detect CTRL+Click on SWT ToolItem

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to detect a CTRL-click on a ToolItem? I want to distinguish between CTRL+Click and normal mouse click.

```java
ToolBar toolbar= new ToolBar(parent, SWT.NONE);
ToolItem saveToolItem = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
...
saveToolItem.addSelectionListener(SelectionListener.widgetSelectedAdapter(e -> {
    // if CTRL+Click {
    //     specialSave();
    // } else
    normalSave();
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectionEvent` passed to the event (in `e` in your code) has a `stateMask` field including the modifier keys being pressed. The `SWT.CTRL` constant for Ctrl.

So:

```java
if ((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL)
```

Tests for the Ctrl key being pressed